# Is it possible to install IE10 on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-10

Some Windows 8 users claim that IE10 is fast and better than IE9. I want to know if it is possible to install IE10 on my Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not yet. Windows 7 will eventually be supported, but they haven't released IE 10 for it yet. Currently the only way to get IE 10 is by running Win 8 (either a preview or the RTM).

[See this](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9228533/Where_s_IE10_for_Windows_7_)

Answer (score 1):

This question is from last year. I just want complete this question for user that are still searching for this question.

You can install on Win7 with Service Pack 1.

The download page for IE10 is http://windows.microsoft.com/de-de/internet-explorer/ie-10-worldwide-languages.